# Why is the code that I copy and Pasted from above is not working and darkened in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, function

I am writing a simple Rock Paper Scissor code Using JavaScript and for some reason the code isn't working and the part of code that I Copy and pasted from above is darkened which is probably showing that part of code contains the error but I cannot seem to find it
Here is the full code and the part which is darkened is after 'You lose' statement of the first condition in the fifth last statement or line 31st

```
const playertext = document.querySelector('#playertext')
const computertext = documment.querySelector('#computertext')
const resultext = documment.querySelector('#resultext')
const choiceBtn = document.querySelectorAll('#choiceBtn')
let player;
let computer;
let result;
choiceBtn.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  player = button.textContent
  computeresult()
  playertext.textContent = '`Player:${player}`'
  computertext.textContent = '`Computer:${computer}`'
  resultext.textContent = checkWinner()
}))

function computeresult() {
  const randnumber = Math.floor(Math.random * 3) + 1;
  switch (randnumber) {
    case 1:
      computer = 'Rock'
      break;
    case 2:
      computer = 'Paper'
      break;
    case 3:
      computer = 'Scissor'
  }
}

function checkWinner() {
  if (player === computer) {
    return 'Draw!!'
  }
  elseif(computer == 'Rock')
  return (player == 'Paper') ? 'You win' : 'You lose'
  elseif(computer == 'Paper')
  return (player == 'Scissor') ? 'You win' : 'You lose'
  elseif(computer == 'Scissor')
  return (player == 'Rock') ? 'You win' : 'You lose'
}
```

I was expecting the program of rock paper scissor to work but it doesn't and the code which is darkened is after 'You lose' statement of the first condition in the fifth last statement or line 31st (which I guess contains the error)

Answer (score 0):

- `elseif` is not a valid javascript keyword: you mean `else if`
  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp
- I recommend that you always use curly braces around blocks (e.g. for `else if`)
- and `documment` is a typo (no double `m`)